# UPSERT in MySQL when NOT using Primary Key

Tags: mysql, upsert

I've got a large dataset that I want to import into my MySQL database (using Workbench or Sequel Pro).

The issue is that some rows already exist, and I don't want to duplicate them.

My table structure is similar to

```
| uid  | year | data1 | data2 |
|------|------|-------|-------|
| 123  | 2017 | 12345 | abcde |
| 124  | 2017 | 23453 | abdfe |
| 124  | 2016 | 23413 | agrfe |
| 123  | 2016 | 12325 | addde |
| 101  | 2016 | 12325 | adddf |
| 112  | 2017 | 12366 | fgdsd |
| 146  | 2016 | 11111 | adddj |
```

Eg, in the table above:

`101`, `2017` *doesn't* exist, so I'd want to insert it along with the `year` and `data1`, `data2`

`123`, `2017` *does* exist, so I'd want to update `data1`, `data2` with given values, where `year = 2017`

Comment: Short answer not possible.. For `UPSERT` in MySQL you need to have a primary or unique key.and there is no way to simulate it with normal qeuries unless you are going stored procedure or it might also be possible with dynamic SQL. (but that's not going to work when importing from a other program)

Comment: It doesn't have to specifically use `UPSERT` just replicate the functionality. Eg update if found, else insert.

Comment: Can you not add a unique key?

Answer (score 1):

As your requirement is not on primary key , so you need to use procedure:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS myUpsert;
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE myUpsert (IN vuid INT, IN vyear INT, IN vdata1 INT, IN vdata2 varchar(20))        
BEGIN
DECLARE existingCounter INT;
  SET existingCounter = (SELECT COUNT(*) from tablename
  WHERE uid=vuid  AND year=vyear);

IF existingCounter=0 THEN
 INSERT INTO tablename (uid,year,data1,data2) 
 VALUES (vuid,vyear,vdata1,vdata2);
ELSE
 UPDATE tablename SET data1=vdata1,data2=vdata2
 WHERE uid=vuid AND year=vyear;
 END IF;
END
|
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: "I've got a large dataset that I want to import into my MySQL database (using Workbench or Sequel Pro)." With this SP means he is going to do this manual

Comment: "opps - then it will not work" Well what if you make a BEFORE INSERT trigger that one would fire when you import from a program.. (i need to go so i can't write that trigger right now).. Besides coverting this SP code into the needed trigger code is almost copy and paste.

Comment: yes, agreed with you, i hardly write trigger now, so it was not in my mind at all :)